# Symfony blackknight467 StarRatingBundle is unable to find template

Tags: php, symfony, twig, symfony4, symfony-3.4

I have installed blackknight467/StarRatingBundle on a Symfony 3.4 project and after setting up the form it shows the following error:

> Unable to find template "StarRatingBundle::rating.html.twig" (looked
>   into: /var/www/test/app/Resources/views,
>   /var/www/test/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/Resources/views/Form).

/src/AppBundle/Controller/CommentsController.php

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder()
   ->add('review_rating', RatingType::class, ['stars' => 5])
   ->getForm();

return $this->render('@App\Comments\index.html.twig', ['form' => $form->createView()]);
```

/src/AppBundle/Resources/views/Comments/index.html.twig

```
{{form_widget(form.review_rating)}}
```

/vendor/blackknight467/star-rating-bundle/blackknight467/StarRatingBundle/Form/RatingType.php

```
namespace blackknight467\StarRatingBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\NumberType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormView;

class RatingType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
    {
        $view->vars = array_replace($view->vars, [
            'stars' => $options['stars']
        ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'attr' => [
                'class' => 'rating',
            ],
            'scale' => 1,
            'stars' => 5,
        ]);
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return NumberType::class;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'rating';
    }
}
```

I have looked for similar issues in StackOverflow but even by doing the workarounds in them this could not be resolved. How can I fix this?

Comment: can you show your `formType.php`?

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber not having formType.php. Using the controller based form builder.

Comment: then could you show the code from your controller?

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber updated the question with source.

Comment: your code looks alright. Try re-installing the bundle. The file Symfony should be looking for is located in `vendor/blackknight467/star-rating-bundle/blackknight467/StarRatingBundle/Resources/views/rating.html.twig`. Otherwise simply copy this file to `/var/www/test/app/Resources/views`.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber rating.html.twig is there in vendor. Will try copying that file to views.

Comment: @DirkJ.Faber re-installing or moving the twig file did not work. No other changes were made to any of the bundle files upon installation.

Comment: maybe you forgot to register the bundle in `app/appKernel.php` ?